# How to display the query result on the php page after the server receive QR scan result from client phone which act as QR Scanner

Tags: php, android, mysql, cordova, qr-code

I'm using PhoneGap to create a Android QR code scanning app which act as a client, while the server is using PHP with MySQL (WAMP). Below is the section of QR scanning app to send the scanned result to the server, it manage to send and get reply from server, so I think the problem is at my server code in the next section

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://192.168.1.2/receiveQR.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        QR: result.text
    },
    success: function(response) {
        $('#result').html(''); //clean the field
        alert("QR sent to server successfully");
        $("#result").append(response + '<br/>');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Not working!');
    }
});
```

Server code: to receive the QR scanned result as input then use the input to retrieve record from MySQL database to display the result on PHP page immediately, although my code can successfully retrieve the record from db, but the ECHO is show on my Android APP and not my server PHP interface.

I want to achieve result like Library Barcode Scanning result, is my method wrong?

```
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['QR'])){  //check is the QR result is empty or not
  $qr = $_POST['QR'];   //QR scanned result send from APP to server
  $tablename = "book";
  $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

      if(!mysql_select_db("testing", $db)){
         print mysql_error();
  }
  if(!empty($qr)) {
    $sql="SELECT bk_title FROM ".$tablename." WHERE bk_id = '".$qr."'";
    $retval = mysql_query($sql, $db);
    if(! $retval){
        die("Cound not get data: ".mysql_error());
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)){
        echo "Book Title :{$row['bk_title']} <br> ";
    }
    mysql_close($db);
  }     
  $reply = "Server Received";
  print json_encode($reply);
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: let me know so I can assist you

Comment: what is the info do you need? I do not know what info you need..most already stated up there...the two answers below cannot work..

Comment: i create a php script for you

Comment: as you can see, my android app that built using phonegap successfully send the scanned result to server, what my server need to do is use that result sent from android app to query out the database info and SHOW IT ON THE PHP PAGE, for example i will scan book ID, server side will retrieve the Book Title and show it

Comment: This question has attracted two substantial-looking answers, but they "didn't work" - so I think it's appropriate to close as unclear. The user has not logged in since asking anyway.

Comment: (The code within this question is also completely unsafe to use - SQL injection vuln).

Answer (score 0):

You did couple of mistakes over here.
Please replace your code with below code:

```
$.ajax({        
            url         : "http://192.168.1.2/receiveQR.php",
            dataType: "json"
            type        : 'POST',
            data        : { QR : result.text},        
            success     : function(response){
                   $('#result').html(''); //clean the field
                   alert("QR sent to server successfully");             
                   $("#result").append(response.data + '<br/>');  
            },
            error       : function() {
                alert('Not working!');
            }
        });



<?php
 if(isset($_POST['QR']))
 {  
      //check is the QR result is empty or not
      $qr = $_POST['QR'];   //QR scanned result send from APP to server
      $tablename = "book";
      $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

          if(!mysql_select_db("testing", $db)){
             print mysql_error();
      }
      if(!empty($qr)) {
      $reply=array();
        $sql="SELECT bk_title FROM ".$tablename." WHERE bk_id = '".$qr."'";
        $retval = mysql_query($sql, $db);
        if(! $retval){
            die("Cound not get data: ".mysql_error());
        }
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)){
            $reply['data'] = "Book Title :{$row['bk_title']} <br> ";
        }
        mysql_close($db);
      }     
      $reply['message'] = "Server Received";
      print json_encode($reply);
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: doesn't work, output still display on the phone app itself...
your method just put the output on the phone app in AN ARRAY form..

i think php page itself cannot auto refresh to show result..need some kind of trigger...but i no idea how...

Comment: Note that this replicates the **SQL injection** problem from the original post. If you spot this sort of thing, please do at least make a note in your answer, if not also fixing it too, and drawing attention to the fix.

Answer (score 0):

use this one

javascript

```
formData = {
    QR: result.text
}
$.ajax({
    url: "http://192.168.1.2/receiveQR.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function(response) {
        $('#result').html(''); //clean the field
        alert("QR sent to server successfully");
        $("#result").append(response + '<br/>');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Not working!');
    }
});
```

php

```
<?php
      if(isset($_POST['QR'])){  //check is the QR result is empty or not
  $qr = $_POST['QR'];   //QR scanned result send from APP to server
  $tablename = "book";
  $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

      if(!mysql_select_db("testing", $db)){
         print mysql_error();
  }
  if(!empty($qr)) {
    $sql="SELECT bk_title FROM ".$tablename." WHERE bk_id = '".$qr."'";
    $retval = mysql_query($sql, $db);
    if(! $retval){
        die("Cound not get data: ".mysql_error());
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)){
        echo "Book Title :{$row['bk_title']} <br> ";
    }
    mysql_close($db);
  }     
  $reply = "Server Received";
  print json_encode($reply);
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: doesn't work, output still display on the phone app itself...i think php page itself cannot auto refresh to show result..need some kind of trigger...but i no idea how...

Comment: Note that this replicates the **SQL injection** problem from the original post. If you spot this sort of thing, please do at least make a note in your answer, if not also fixing it too, and drawing attention to the fix.